# How to stop jobservice when the user exits/closes the app?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I have implemented JobService for my app. The job makes an API call. This has to be done every 4 minutes.

Also the job should start only when the app is being used and should stop when the user exits the app.

I am using setPeriodic to make it run every 4 minutes.

I am planning to do stop/cancel the job in onStop activity lifecycle method. But how do I make sure that the job is stopped/cancelled while the user closes the app?

In onStartJob method, I am returning false once I receive the response for my api call. Will this stop the job? or should I do something else?

Comment: in onDestroy() or onStop()  methods of activity just call the jobschedulerservice and cancel all the pending jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum period for a job to run using job scheduler is 15 minutes in the standard AOSP. So `JobService` doesn't look like the right thing to use for your problem. You should look into [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services), detach when exiting the application. Your 4 min logic should be implemented manually inside the service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am facing this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136177/background-execution-in-oreo-android-devices

Comment: Can I use handler to schedule every 4 mins and inside that start and end job service(service makes an api call). So on exit of the app, I will cancel the job using the job id. is this possible? thank you

Comment: Yes it is one the the possible approaches.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please let me know if job service can fix my issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136177/background-execution-in-oreo-android-devices

Comment: Nope. Job scheduler is meant for background tasks, Communicating between activities can be done via an interface callback

Comment: could you please explain more about this solution? Any article to read? Mine is cordova app. First activity is a WebView. Javascript calls stop after 5 mins of going in background. How to make the javascript calls to run even when the activity is in background?